# Python - If statement not functioning inside def() function

Tags: python, if-statement

I hope someone can help me with this issue.

```
from tkinter import *#This enables me to use the tkinter commands
window=Tk()#This declares the window
window.title("Binary-Denary converters")#This defines the name of the window
loop=1

def selection():
  global submitbutton
  global variable
  global choice#This declares the variable so it can be used anywhere in the code
  label1=Label(window,text="Submit 1 for D-B \nSubmit 2 for B-D ")#This tells the user what to input
  label1.pack()
  variable= StringVar(window)
  variable.set("")
  choice=OptionMenu(window, variable,"1  ", "2  ")
  choice.pack()
  submitbutton=Button(window, text="Submit",command=getinput)
  submitbutton.pack()

def getinput():
  global variable
  global userinput
  userinput=variable.get()#This takes the users input and assigns it to a variable
  print(userinput)
  if userinput =="1":
      DToB()
  else:
      BToD()

def DToB():
  display1=Label(window, text="D to B")
  display1.pack()
  submitbutton.destroy()

def BToD():
  display2=Label(window, text="B to D ")
  display2.pack()
  submitbutton.destroy() 

selection()
```

The user has a drop down list, and selects 1 for DToB and 2 for BToD, the program is able to identify the number that the user chose and I checked it does this by printing userinput. I have also checked and it is a str value that comes from this drop down list I confirmed this by adding userinput to userinput which gave me 1 1 instead of 2 if it was an int.

The issue is with the if statement " if userinput =="1" " in the getinput() function which even when userinput does = 1 just goes with what is in the else part of the statement.

I have used if statements like this in very similar codes before so I cannot understand what I have done wrong.

Here is some pictures of the program running 
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDGtH.png) [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgbUp.png)

Comment: The code below `def getInput():` isn't part of the `getInput` function because it isn't indented.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think `getinput()` returns the *index* of the value, not the value itself.

Comment: @Ben: If his indentation actually looks like that, he would have a SyntaxError, but he isn't complaining about that.

Comment: Please don't post code with screwed up indentation. If you post python code without the correct indentation, we can't tell what's caused by your indentation, and what's caused by other problems.

Comment: Indentation corrected, I didn't realize that copying it messed up the indentation @Ben

Comment: Indentation corrected, I didn't realize that copying it messed up the indentation @khelwood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
choice = OptionMenu(window, variable, "1  ", "2  ")
```

When the user chooses 1, the value of the `StringVar` is actually set to `"1  "`, not `"1"`. Either change the values of the option menu or change `if userinput == "1"` to `if userinput = "1  "`, and your code will behave as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much, fixed and working as I intended. I completely discarded the formatting from the OptionMenu, didn't even occur to me.